# Enumerating Available Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to programmatically enumerate available code first migrations (EF 6+) for a particular context / assembly?

Specifically, I'd like to look at a particular assembly/context and list the available migrations as well as sort them by order in which they're applied.

It seems like the System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationAssembly is what I want, but it's internal. Short of using reflection to get at it, is there a better way?

**EDIT**

For an example application that looks at two different EF assemblies and gives you a "diff" of their migrations, see: [EF Code First Migrations to Deploy Older Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765527/ef-code-first-migrations-to-deploy-older-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var config = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);

var all = migrator.GetLocalMigrations().ToList()
var applied = migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations().ToList();
var pending = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
```

Comment: Ah, so this returns the name of the migration - including the timestamp, which is what allows me to order them properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DbMigrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```
var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
config.MigrationsAssembly = YourAssembly;
config.TargetDatabase = YourDb;
var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
var local = migrator.GetLocalMigrations(); //all migrations
var pending = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
var applied = migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations();
```